# Can you intercept or overwrite an IPreviewHandler of docx files?

Tags: winapi, com, ms-office, vsto, windows-explorer

In my previous investigation I discovered that even though windows file explorer launches word.exe in an embedded state the Documents collection remains empty.

[Excel and word opened in Windows Explorer preview panel have Workbooks.Count and Documents.Count equal to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618812/excel-and-word-opened-in-windows-explorer-preview-panel-have-workbooks-count-and)

A bit further research when I made the embedded applications [visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839544.aspx) they would load with out a document inside of it:
[image: empty word]

```
public static class WordAppExt
{
    public static Word.Document GetActiveDoc(this Word.Application App)
    {
        try
        {
            App.Visible = true;
            if (App.Documents.Count > 0)
            {
                return App.ActiveDocument;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

SO I came to the conclusion that explorer only needs to launch word, but it does not have the documents hosted inside of word. which means windows explorer is likely a [IOleContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690103(v=vs.85).aspx). If true this means any object embedded in the preview pane can be accessed via [EnumObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687224(v=vs.85).aspx).

Unfortunately my code runs in a VSTO addin, I don't have access to the explorer com objects so I can't do a [QI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IOleContainer. But I have a theory that there maybe another way of accessing the Document COM object, through the PreviewHandler. I think that the reason Word, Powerpoint, and Excel get launched is either to register or initialization of the previewHandler?

So HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers has a list of guids associated with [IPreviewHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for different file types.

There are plenty of articles about how to create your own previewHandler for new file types:

- [Building Preview Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [How to Register a Preview Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144144(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [PreviewHandler.cs](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/blob/ae73c1294fe9d47c5052d090b945f69a6364e3a8/source/WindowsAPICodePack/ShellExtensions/PreviewHandlers/PreviewHandler.cs)
- [Hosting Preview Handlers in Windows Forms Applications](http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/79)
- [Preview Handlers Revisited](http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/183)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19744/Using-Preview-Handlers-in-Windows-Vista
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppShellExtPreviewHandler-58db53b8

But I want to replace Words Preview Handler with my own. If I can't replace it I'd be more than happy to intercept the existing Preview Handler.

Comment: The only way to intercept it is to write and register your own PreviewHandler for the desired file type(s) and have it internally delegate to the previously registered PreviewHelper that you are replacing. A file type can only have 1 PreviewHandler registered at a time.